# Ember valueBinding to Redactor WYSIWYG

Tags: ember.js

I'm using the Redactor WYSIWYG editor and it allows you to use minimal markup before initializing its code like this:

```
<textarea id="redactor" name="content">
…
</textarea>
```

However during initialization Redactor will wrap this `textarea` with the following content:

```
<div class="redactor_box">
  <div class="redactor_ redactor_editor" contenteditable="true" dir="ltr">
    …
  </div>
  <textarea id="redactor" name="content" style="display: none;">
    …
  </textarea>
</div>
```

I currently have done this in Ember

Template:

```
{{ view App.RedactorView valueBinding='contentAttributes.headerContent' class='header-redactor' name='headerContent' }}
```

View extending Ember.TextArea:

```
App.RedactorView = Ember.TextArea.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $("#"+this.elementId).redactor();
  }
});
```

This still holds a binding to the `textarea` (now hidden), but I now need to bind the `redactor_editor` class instead. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit of digging in the Redactor code I found out that if your element destined to be an editor is not a `textarea` element, Redactor will do the reverse thing and add the `textarea` if your a using a `div` instead for example.

Updated my view and tweaked it based on code from Ember.TextArea and Ember.TextSupport so it would get the correct value, this will probably work fine if you're using a `contenteditable` enabled element as well.

```
App.RedactorView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  init: function() {
    this._super();

    this.on("focusOut", this, this._elementValueDidChange);
    this.on("change", this, this._elementValueDidChange);
    this.on("paste", this, this._elementValueDidChange);
    this.on("cut", this, this._elementValueDidChange);
    this.on("input", this, this._elementValueDidChange);
  },
  _updateElementValue: Ember.observer(function() {
    var $el, value;
    value = Ember.get(this, "value");
    $el = this.$().context;
    if ($el && value !== $el.innerHTML) {
      return $el.innerHTML = value;
    }
  }, "value"),
  _elementValueDidChange: function() {
    var $el;
    $el = this.$().context;
    return Ember.set(this, "value", $el.innerHTML);
  },
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().redactor();
    this._updateElementValue();
  }
});
```

Here's a JSBin demonstrating it: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cefebepa/1/edit

Comment: Could you try to setup a working example with the latest version of ember on jsbin please. I can't manage to make this work :(

Comment: This wont work with latest version of Redactor aka v9.2

Comment: @Rajat are you sure? The jsbin is liking to the latest js/css and it seems ok to me.

Comment: I tried it with v9.2 and it didn't work. I dont understand how it might as from their docs, they have removed support for events on the redactor object. The API in v9.2 still supports callbacks but the syntax is very different.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Ember + Foundation, and kroofy's solution worked like a charm for me.

The height of the contentEditable were loading without paddings (were missing a paragraph), so ive changed to redactor's insertHtml method to update the value.

from:

```
return $el.innerHTML = value;
```

to:

```
return this.$().redactor('insertHtml', value);
```

thanks kroofy.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you want to access the Ember View's DOM element, you should use this:

```
this.$()
```

instead of

```
$("#"+this.elementId)
```

About the Redactor issue... I am not sure how wise it is to tie up the Ember code with the WYSIWYG editor's functionality, but if you are determined about it, you can do the following:

```
App.RedactorView = Ember.TextArea.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var box = this.$().closest('.' + this.elementId + '_box');
    box.find('.' + this.elementId + '_redactor_editor').redactor();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get this working, will post my answer in a moment.